# SELF keyword in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, methods, instance-variables, instance-methods

In a project I'm creating, I have various classes. One of my classes has an instance of NSMutableArray that holds objects of another one of my classes. I thought I had a firm understanding on this topic, but somehow it got jumbled up in my mind again.

When initializing an instance of this class, I have this initilize method:

```
- (MMShowMovement *) initWithMovementName: (NSString *) name andNumber: (NSInteger) number {

 if( [super init] ) {

  [self setMovementTitle: name];
  [self setMovementNumber: number];

  [self setDotArray: [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

 }

 return self;

}
```

Later on, after an instance of this class is created, I can add objects to the NSMutableArray "dotArray." Here is that method.

```
- (void) addDot: (MMDot *) dot {

 [dotArray addObject: dot]; 

}
```

(I know, its simple) I'm wondering, when I use "dotArray" in this method, I am accessing the dotArray object for the instance of the class for which this method has been invoked, correct? Or should I use the self keyword here also?

```
- (void) addDot: (MMDot *) dot {

 [[self dotArray] addObject: dot]; 

}
```

Honestly, I'm not really sure. I believe it is the former, but I'm unsure as to why. And it is not necessary to use the self keyword in this method, why do I have to use it in the initializer to access the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we'll write

```
self = [super init]
```

Because *super*'s initialization method might return an object that’s not the same as the one that was allocated. So that's why we use *self* in initxxx method and we don't need to use *self* in other kinds of methods.

I learned this stuff clearly from the book Learn Objective-C on the Mac, Chap 10 Object Initialization, Mark Dalrymple and Scott Knaster, Apress.

A excerpt from the book:
instance variables are found at a memory location that’s a fixed distance from the hidden self parameter. If a new object is returned from an init method, we need to *update self* so that any subsequent instance variable references affect the right places in memory.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! I was rereading through parts of the Kochan book trying to straighten it out again..

Comment: Maybe you can also check the definitive document: The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language from Apple Developer website, especially Ch3 Allocating and Initializing Objects.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is a pointer to the current receiver - It refers to the object that received a message.
You can use self to get access to the object that performs the current method.

In your case, this means that if object X of type `MMShowMovement` receives an `addDot:` message, self contains a pointer to X.
You can access `dotArray` in three different ways:

```
[dotArray addObject:dot]; //directly access the instance variable dotArray
[[self dotArray] addObject:dot]; //access dotArray with an accessor method
//--or--
[self.dotArray addObject:dot]; //access dotArray with an accessor method using dot-syntax
```

---

If you are using automatic KVO notifications, you have to use the accessors (instead of directly manipulating the ivar) to trigger notifications.
To ensure that a variable is accessed via its accessor method, you have to prefix `self.`

Answer (score 2):

[self dotArray] calls the "dotArray" selector (method) of the object. If there is no such method, you'll get an error. You cannot access the instance variable this way, unless it's a property and you've synthesized this getter method for it.

[dotArray addObject] simply accesses the variable and calls a built-in method that is specified by NSMutableArray.

[self setMovementTitle:], [self setMovementNumber:] and [self setDotArray:] are all method calls. You always need an object reference for method calls.

In init, you may as well have said [dotArray addObject] (after initing the variable, of course).

Comment: Do you mean that he could have written `dotArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` in `-(id)init`

Comment: swegi: yes, maybe, although maybe setDotArray also does something else.